# Number of monthly active users on a telegram channel?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, node-telegram-bot-api

telegram offers a measure of views of messages on a channel. I’m curious if there is a way to measure monthly active users or total unique views on a monthly basis on a particular group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer : **Yes**.

You can analyse your channel statistics or even other channels statistics with many online tools or bots.

[This](https://tgstat.com/) is one of them that you can check this items via it. I should notice that all details also are available in graph.

[image]

1. **Count of Subscribers**
2. **Count of Views**
3. **Avg post reach**
4. **Posts**
5. **Forwards & channel mentions**

You also can do it by making your own bot to checkout all of this details.

If you wonder how this website do this, I should say I don't have any specific information about it but maybe can try a research and answer. Anyway **public** Telegram channels are available in such address:

> **https://t.me/s/ChannelName**

for example :

> **https://t.me/s/Durov**

is Pavel Durov's Telegram channel.
and also in this [link](https://tgstat.com/channel/@durov) you can checkout it's statistics online.